# Upload a edited document to SharePoint online and keep the properties that already have been set

Tags: document-library, online, custom-properties

In SharePoint online i have a document library and created custom properties that the user needs to fill in. So far it is fine. But if the user re upload the file. This property is empty again.

But what i do expect that if i re upload the same file and i say you need to add it as a new version that the custom property will be set.

My question is: Is this just how it work will i lose all the custom properties i did already set in the previous version?

[image: Proof 1]
[image]